# django set img src statically using default

Tags: django

I am new to django. I have two different `img` tags in my form like this
(while loading profile page, if user has saved profile image (which is sent to me by json) its image will be shown and if not a default image is shown)

```
{% if widget.value.url %}
    <img src="{{ widget.value.url }}" alt="" id="profile_image" height="200px" width="200px">
{% else %}
    <img src="{% static 'utils/user.png' %}" id="profile_image" alt="" height="200px" width="200px">
{% endif %}
```

now I want to merge these two using something like this

```
<img src={{widget.value.url|default:{% static 'utils/user.png' %}}} id="profile_image" alt=""height="200px" width="200px">
```

but that has error and I have tried different types but none works
how can I do that exactly?
Thanks

Comment: Why this is happening with you, when the user change the profile picture the url will change to the new picture.

Comment: that's for the time i'm loading profile page..i get a json object and should check if he has picture i should show it and if not show the default image instead @mohammedqudah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first assign the static url to a variable:

```
{% static 'utils/user.png' as default_image %}
<img src="{{widget.value.url|default:default_image}}">
```